# Spark ALS Model Broadcast

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, recommendation-engine

I have a problem with the ALS recommendation of Spark. I want to predict foreach user in my system the products using the following code

```
users = ... # RDD definition here
als_model = ... # trained ALS model
recommendations = [als_model.recommendProducts(u, 5) for u in users.collect()]
```

The problem with this piece of code is, that it is not really parallelized.
I would prefer something like

```
recommendations = users.map(lambda u: als_model.recommendProducts(u, 5))
```

Unfortunately that's not possible, because I cannot use the als_model inside of an Spark action.

Another option for me would be to execute

```
als_model.recommendProductsForUsers(1000)
```

This returns the top 1000 products for all users (that's what I try to achieve ;))
But this method consumes way to much memory and in the end I get a GC error because of a heap space overflow.

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this problem as efficient as possible?

Comment: which spark version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

From the book "Advanced Analytics in Spark", which was mostly based on Spark 1.3 (page 56):

> At the moment, however, Spark MLlib's ALS implementation does not
>   support a method to recommend to all users. It is possible to
>   recommend to one user at a time, although each will launch a
>   short-lived distributed job that takes a few seconds.

There's also an example which does it with 100 users, and it uses the same looping you are trying to achieve, so there's no better way currently to do it.

Also note that `recommendProducts(...)` still runs in a distributed way, so the performance you are losing here theoretically is because the jobs are quite short and submitted and collected quite frequently. So one big job would require less coordination than more smaller ones.

Comment: My problem is, that this is too slow. I've 500.000 users and in the future there will be more. Do you have any idea, why the method recommendProductsForUsers results in GC errors? This method seems to work more in parallel and would be faster.

Comment: That should still work fine since your model is already ready. How much does it take now? Are you sure you used caching?

Comment: It takes 8GB RAM now, and crashes. I don't have more RAM on my local machine to test it. But it should be enough, because it's not that much data (500.000 user, 1000 products, 2.500.000 ratings)
What do you mean with caching?

Comment: Using `persist()` or `cache()`.